# Как убрать angular material progress bar?

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-material

У нас на проекте настроено так, что при переходе на какую-либо страницу, всплывает angular material progress bar. После завершения загрузки страницы, когда мы уже перешли на другую, прогресс бар пропадает.

Моя проблема: Я создал `canActivate` сервис, который ловит, может пользователь перейти по кнопке или нет. Сервис сначала проверяет, затем, если мы можем пройти, грузится страница, если нет - выводит сообщение о том, что мы не можем посетить страницу. После показа сообщения, мы никуда не переходим, остаёмся на той странице, где и были. Но `progress bar` в это время крутится.

progress-bar подвязан на `Actions`(`ROUTER_NAVIGATION`, `ROUTER_NAVIGATED`) через @Effects(). То есть, получается, когда `router` начинает грузить новую страничку (`ROUTER_NAVIGATION`) - появляется progress-bar; `ROUTER_NAVIGATED` - исчезает

Вопрос: **Как мне убирать `progress bar` если мы никуда не переходим и обновлять страницу будет не самым лучшим вариантом?**

Comment: создай, пожалуйста, _воспроизводимый пример_ на codesandbox :)

Comment: @overthesanity, боюсь что не получится на codesandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилась проблема так:

Так как прогресс бар был привязан к двум `action` `angular router`, я решил посмотреть какие есть ещё `action` у него. В итоге оказалось, что в дополнении к этим двум:

- `ROUTER_NAVIGATION`
- `ROUTER_NAVIGATED`

Есть ещё три:

- `ROUTER_REQUEST`
- `ROUTER_CANCEL`
- `ROUTER_ERROR`

Я тупо трижды скопипастил код, который контроллировал `ROUTER_NAVIGATED` и изменил названия событий. Запустив проект, увидел, что всё работает. Затем комментировал методы для того, чтобы найти нужный. В итоге, `action` `ROUTER_CANCEL` явился победителем. Спасибо